# Primary Key set to Auto Increment, but still receiving Field doesn't have a default value

Tags: mysql

I'm using this mysql table and attempting to insert the first entry into the table but receive #1364 - Field 'subdivision_replaces_id' doesn't have a default value as an error, despite the field being set as the primary key, not null, and auto increment.

```
CREATE TABLE `countries_subdivisions` (
  `subdivision_id` int(5) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `subdivision_country_id` int(3) NOT NULL,
  `subdivision_name_en` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `subdivision_name_native` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `subdivision_name_native_language` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `subdivision_iso_3166_2_code` varchar(5) NOT NULL,
  `subdivision_two_letter` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
  `subdivision_category` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `subdivision_created_by` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `subdivision_created_on` datetime NOT NULL,
  `subdivision_replaces_id` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `subdivision_replaced_by` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `subdivision_replaced_on` datetime NOT NULL,
  `subdivision_status` int(1) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`subdivision_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

I can't identify anything that would cause this issue.  Any ideas?

Comment: `subdivision_replaces_id` isn't the primary key, `subdivision_id` is. The `subdivision_` prefix on the table is probably making it hard to read.

Comment: Incidentally, note that the number in parentheses following an int declaration is almost entirely meaningless